# Can't read PHAsset content asynchronous

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to read specified file (photo from camera roll) asynchronous, but it does not work for me.

Variable `tempData` gets `nil` untill I change config `requestOptionForPhotos.synchronous` to `YES`, then everything is ok, but I don't want to perform this code synchronous.

Is it possible that I'm blocking access to photo by requesting to the same file in other thread? I'm newbie in objective-c and iOS programming and I don't know how does it works.

```
  NSURL *assetUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:filepath];
  PHFetchResult *collection = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:[NSArray arrayWithObject:assetUrl] options:nil];

  PHImageRequestOptions *requestOptionForPhotos = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
  requestOptionForPhotos.networkAccessAllowed = YES;
  requestOptionForPhotos.synchronous = NO;

  __block BOOL isFinished = NO;
  __block NSData * tempData = nil;

  for(PHAsset *asset in collection) {
    [[PHImageManager defaultManager]
     requestImageForAsset:asset
     targetSize:CGSizeMake(80, 80)
     contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill
     options:requestOptionForPhotos
     resultHandler:^(UIImage *result, NSDictionary *info) {
       tempData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(result);
       isFinished = YES;
     }];
  }
```

Comment: are you getting valid file path? also, is there any data you are getting in "collection" object?

Comment: Yes, there are some data and path also is valid.

Answer (score 1):

```
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
         NSURL *assetUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:filepath];
         PHFetchResult *collection = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:[NSArray arrayWithObject:assetUrl] options:nil];
         PHImageRequestOptions *requestOptionForPhotos = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
         requestOptionForPhotos.networkAccessAllowed = YES;
         requestOptionForPhotos.synchronous = NO;

        __block BOOL isFinished = NO;
        __block NSData * tempData = nil;

       for (PHAsset *asset in collection) {
           [[PHImageManager defaultManager] 
                      requestImageForAsset:asset
                      targetSize:CGSizeMake(80, 80)
                      contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill
                      options:requestOptionForPhotos
                      resultHandler:^(UIImage *result, NSDictionary *info) {
                           tempData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(result);
                           isFinished = YES;
           }];
       }
    });
```

try this code to get asynchronusly image and put breakpoint on result handdler to check weather you are getting image or not.